# The apache2 configtest failed

Tags: server, apache2

Apache2 is not working when I try to reload the Apache2 error msg is coming. I am very new to server and Apache2 could you please help to run the apache2. Below is the error code.

```
:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                                                                   *
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
(20)Not a directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
(20)Not a directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost define                          d at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf:1
(20)Not a directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost define                          d at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1
AH00014: Configuration check failed
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(20)Not a directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/'
```

Check if *`/var/log/apache2`* **directory** exists and Apache has read-write access to it.

Comment: there is /var/log/ as a directory inside there is a file called apache2

Comment: /etc/apache2 directory is available

Comment: /var/log/apache2 must be a directory that the user apache runs under has read-write access to. Remove or rename the file 'apache2' and make a directory.

Comment: now i have made a directory then i tried to reload the apache2. {sudo service apache2 reload} ia m getting error [ * Reloading web server apache2                                                                                                   *
 * Apache2 is not running
]

Comment: Then you have to start it instead: 'sudo service apache start'

Comment: yes now its working thank you very much @soren A

Comment: @SorenA Apache log files aren't owned by the apache user. They are owned by the `root` user and the `adm` group. With permissions of `640` on files and and `750` on directories. So in fact, the `www-data` user doesn't even have the rights to list the content of `/var/log/apache2`. The problem was just that `/var/log/apache2` was a file instead of a directory.

Comment: @Dan, I didn't write that the apache user, www-data, needed execute rights in the directory, just rw !!

Comment: @SorenA That was a poor choice of words from my part, sorry. What I was trying to say was that apache doesn't need any kind of permissions on the log files (which is the case by default). Apache logs are actually written by root.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no folder `/var/log/apache2/` Apache will not be able to write logs there.

So create it first `mkdir /var/log/apache2` , or change log folder in apache.conf to something different.

Be sure that permissions are correct as well. `chmod 750  /var/log/apache2`

Comment: I have tried to create the directory but is saying {mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/apache2’: File exists
}